# Is the runtime of comparing two nodes and then removing Θ(1)?

Tags: python, data-structures, time-complexity, runtime, doubly-linked-list

**So the data structure in question is a doubly linked list.**

Let's say that we needed to compare the data of node next to the header and data of the node next to the trailer. Then, depending on which node's data was bigger, we remove the node with bigger data.

Does this entire process take up Θ(1) time, or is it more complex than that?

Comment: Assuming that you have pointers to the head and tail of the list, then it is O(1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is O(1) because you access the head and tail directly.

Answer (score 1):

The time complexity of the process should be `O(1)`.

Let's see an example:

```
private void removeBiggerNode(LinkedList list) {
     ListNode currHead = list.head;
     ListNode currHeadNext = currHead.next;

     ListNode currTail = list.tail;
     currTailPrev = list.tail.previous;

     if(currHeadNext.val > currTailPrev.val) { 
        currHead.next = currHead.next.next;
        currHead.next.prev = currHead;
     }
     else { 
         tail.prev = tail.prev.prev;
         tail.prev.next = tail;
     }
}
```

The ListNode can be defined as:

```
public class ListNode {
    ListNode next;
    ListNode prev;
    int val;

    // constructor
    ListNode(int val){ this.val = val; }
}
```